# How can i merge arrays like 2048?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I'm trying to merge values on an array like 2048, if you put "A" on the prompt, all the values go to the left, the same occures with the right side.

I was using this code:

```
var vetor = [2,2,4,4],merge=[],vet3 = [],pos=0,number,pos=0,ingame=true,resp; //Variaveis


while(ingame) {
    
    resp = prompt(vetor + "\n" + "Digite [A ou D");
    resp = resp.toUpperCase();
    if (resp == "A") {
        //Movimentação Esquerda
        pos = 0;
        merge = [];
        for (var i =0;i<vetor.length;i++) { //Percorrendo todo o vetor para checar valores 

            if (vetor[i] != 0) { //Se valor atual do vetor for diferente de 0 
                if (vetor[i] == vetor[i+1]) { //E se o valor do vetor1 for igual a próxima posição dele 
                    var soma = vetor[i] + vetor[i+1]; 
                    vetor[i+1] = 0; 
                    merge[pos] = soma;
                } else {

                    merge[pos] = vetor[i];
                }
                pos++;
            } 
        }
        while(merge.length < vetor.length) {
            
            merge.push(0);
        }
        for (var i =0;i<vetor.length;i++) {
            
            vetor[i] = merge[i];
        }
        
    } else if (resp == "D") { //Movimentação Direita
        pos = 0;
        merge = [];
        for (var i =0;i<vetor.length;i++) { //Percorrendo todo o vetor para checar valores 

            if (vetor[i] != 0) { //Se valor atual do vetor for diferente de 0 
                if (vetor[i] == vetor[i+1]) { //E se o valor do vetor1 for igual a próxima posição dele 
                    var soma = vetor[i] + vetor[i+1]; 
                    vetor[i+1] = 0; 
                    merge[pos] = soma;
                } else {

                    merge[pos] = vetor[i];
                }
                pos++;
            } 
        }
        while(merge.length < vetor.length) {
            
            merge.unshift(0);
        }
        for (var i =0;i<vetor.length;i++) {
            
            vetor[i] = merge[i];
        }
    }
    if (resp == "EXIT") {
        
        ingame = false;
    }
}
```

But it only works in an array 1d, I want it in an 2d array and if you put W on the prompt, all values go up, and with S all values go down.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.